# Deleting documents using xe:RestService in Xpages from KendoUI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I have a nice `KendoUI Grid` integrated into my application.

I can write a `CSJS` function in a button that will return the `UNID` of the document that is selected by the user. But then I need to delete the document, either by passing that `UNID` somehow to an `SSJS` command or by calling a rest service over my data.

I am already using a Rest Service to get the data into the grid, but I cannot find anyway to write a delete `REST` service. From the documentation there is a `documentJsonService`, but how do I configure it to delete a document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this link to a blog of Assonos can guide you how to do that.
http://www.assono.de/blog/d6plinks/REST-Services-with-the-XPages-Extension-Library

I think you don't need to specify it in your REST service, but in your call to the REST service